# Selenium issue from getting the driver

Tags: python, selenium

This is the code I have but when I run it

```
from import selenium.webdriver.common.keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\Egg\Desktop\Selenium Project\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

With the error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\PyCharm 2020.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\PyCharm 2020.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Egg/PycharmProjects/SeleniumProject/MultiBrowser.py", line 2
    from import selenium.webdriver.common.keys
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I run Python 3.8.5 not sure what I am doing wrong because I copied it word from word. Unless its a permission issue

Answer (score 2):

Well that's a simple one, you should use `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`, the other way is invalid syntax.

This will import `Keys` which allows you to send special keys such as `ENTER` and `CONTROL` through selenium. You should always read what the error says, this time it said invalid syntax so you should check that.

Comment: I actually tried that as well, and it just greyed out the whole line, and still didnt work, I am also not sure as to what Syntax error i am having an issue from

Comment: @Tommy Please show the code after the change, along with the error